# Dynamic Content Displayed in a Block

Tags: forms, webforms

Site: Drupal 7 with a responsive theme.

I need to display some dynamic content in a block based on the results of a form.

For discussion pursoses.

Field 1 is a drop down of states [NJ, PA, NY]

Field 2 is drop down based on the state of counties and rate. Rates do not have to be shown.

NJ - Middlesex (12), Union(9), Warren(14)

PA - Pike(9), Monroe(8.5), Potter(8)

NY - Essex(9), Lewis(10), Broome(12)

Field three is text box for Total.

Results returned would be new total = total * rate.

If a user selects NJ, Union and Enters a Total of 100, the results returned woulds be 900 (9*100)

It would look something like this:
State [select state]
County [select county based on state]
Total [eneter total]
Amount = rate * total
{Submit}{Reset}

I just have no idea how to do this in Drupal. I do not need to save this data. Just display it to the user.

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Glen